# Image flipped and doesn't scale

Tags: java, android

I have an imageView which rotates the image 90 degrees counter clockwise and where the image doesn't fill the screen.

I have an imageviewer.xml which is defined as:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout 
      android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

I fetch the path of the image (imagePath) from my database and use this code to insert it into the view:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(imagePath);
        img.setImageURI(uri);
```

But when the image shows up in the activity its rotated 90 degrees counter clockwise and doesn't fill the entire screen as it is supposed to - eventhough I've taken the picture on the very same device in portrait mode just before running my app.

Anybody knows whats wrong or what could be wrong?

Comment: Flipped top to bottom or left to right?  Do you mean rotated?  Counter-clockwise?

Comment: I mean rotated - its counter clockwise :/

Comment: if you save the photo to your pc is it also rotated in the same way?

Comment: yes. Do you know how I can turn it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use `setImageMatrix` to rotate and scale the image;

You should also set the image scaletype to `MATRIX`.

```
//you need a matrix
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

// set the scale
matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

// rotate the Bitmap
matrix.postRotate(90);

// then apply it
img.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

There's a good example of this on [anddev.org](http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html)

*UPDATE*

As per the comment made by the originator of the question, a better example can be found at

[Rotating a Bitmap in Android](http://eventuallyconsistent.net/2011/07/21/rotating-a-bitmap-in-android/#comment-18)

Comment: Thanks.. With your help and the help of this article http://eventuallyconsistent.net/2011/07/21/rotating-a-bitmap-in-android/#comment-18, I finally made the bitmap rotate